# What is is the maximum number of consecutive zeros/ones in a TMDS-encoded bitstream?

Tags: hdmi

If I understand correctly, TMDS is similar to the 8b/10b encoding. A compliant 8b/10b encoder will not output more than five ones or zeros in a row, but does a similar property holds true for TMDS?

Comment: I believe it holds true in both. TMDS is just a version of RLL encoding like we used in the 80's with (2,7) code to reduce the transition density and remove DC content.

Comment: https://d3i71xaburhd42.cloudfront.net/00ca4327b49019b6f01073a740a290e72d5e793b/4-Figure4-1.png

Answer (score 5):

While both TMDS and 8b10b are codes to expand 8 bits into 10 bits, they have wildly different objectives. The point of 8b10b is to generate enough transitions to be able to recover bit or symbol clock. The point of TMDS is to minimize transitions because it explicitly transmits a symbol clock.

If you look at the TMDS encoding rules, either the consecutive data bits are XORed or XNORed to form an output symbol bit, which is then further either inverted or not based on cumulative DC balance, it means for certain 8-bit input bytes the 10-bit output symbols can have the 8 consecutive bits of the symbol without a change.

Answer (score -1):

I believe it was introduced the same across the spectrum of 8b/10b codecs.

But in 2017 there was a proposal to reduce the transition density a further amount.
[image]  This also increased the eye-margin and BER.

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/320787581_A_Novel_Stochastic_Model-Based_Eye-Diagram_Estimation_Method_for_8B10B_and_TMDS-Encoded_High-Speed_Channels

It's been almost 4 decades since I did phase margin and eye pattern tests on MFM and RLL codes.  It appears the emphasis is on BW reduction , and increasing the eye pattern rather than reducing the lowest frequency by minimizing the number of consecutive 0's and 1's.  Although both are important for a "matched receiver".

You might also be interested in historical method like Turbo Codes and Viterbi codes that reduce phase modulation spectrum.